# C# Есть ли уязвимость переполнения буфера в int Main(string[] args)

Tags: c#, переполнение

C# Есть ли уязвимость переполнения буфера в int Main(string[] args), если я запускаю program.exe -dfbdfbpofdjbdpofjbpodfjbodp и тд. бесконечно большую строку?

Comment: переполнение может быть при попытке ввести бесконечно большую строку в консоль, еще до вызова программы

Comment: Мне кажется приложение просто крашнется из-за переполнения string

Comment: Думаю, нет, потому что другого способа ведь всё равно нет.

Comment: @Aarnihauta "переполнение" `string` - даже теоретически невозможно, потому что это немутабельный тип данных, вы не можете в строку ничего записать, только читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уязвимость переполнения буфера в языке C# при работе с массивами, пока вы это делаете в безопасном подмножестве языка и не трогаете Marshal, невозможна в принципе.

---

Напомню, что уязвимость переполнения буфера возникает не при любом переполнении буфера, а только при переполнении буфера без обработки этой ситуации и, как следствие, затирании памяти за границами буфера.

Поскольку при доступе к элементам массива границы массива всегда проверяются - уязвимость невозможна.

Answer (score 2):

У размера передаваемых аргументов есть лимит как со стороны консоли (cmd/bash/pwsh), так и со стороны os (CreateProcess, ProcessStartInfo), он зависит от операционки и от консоли, но обычно не превышает десятков мегабайт. Так что до создания процесса и лимита на длину строки в C# просто не дойдёт, упадёт с ошибкой раньше.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, т.к. в качестве аргументов Main принимает один единственный адрес в памяти.